# Exception in Application start method Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to make a program that will switch between JavaFX scenes, however I'm getting a StackOverFlow error that's linking back to `at Login.<init>(Login.java:45)` which is the line `root = FXMLLoader.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Login.fxml"));` in my Login controller class.

**MAIN**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.net.Socket;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main extends Application {

    private Random random = new SecureRandom();

    Socket socket;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Login login = new Login();
        Register register = new Register();

        Scene loginScene = new Scene(login.getContent(), 1152, 648);
        Scene registerScene = new Scene(register.getContent(), 1152, 648);
        loginScene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("Login.css").toExternalForm());
        registerScene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("Register.css").toExternalForm());

        primaryStage.setTitle("Login");
        primaryStage.setScene(loginScene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

}
```

**LOGIN**

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class Login implements Controller {
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane root;

    public Login() throws Exception {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Login.fxml"));
    }

    @Override
    public Parent getContent() {
        return root;
    }
}
```

**FXML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.TextFlow?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="648.0" prefWidth="1152.0" style="-fx-background-color: #2D3447;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Login">
   <children>
      <Text fx:id="invalidCreds" fill="#d00808" layoutX="484.0" layoutY="311.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Invalid username or password" visible="false">
         <font>
            <Font size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </Text>
      <TextField fx:id="usernameTextField" alignment="TOP_LEFT" focusTraversable="false" layoutX="411.0" layoutY="206.0" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="331.0" promptText="Username">
         <font>
            <Font size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </TextField>
      <PasswordField fx:id="passwordField" layoutX="411.0" layoutY="273.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="331.0" promptText="Password">
         <font>
            <Font size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </PasswordField>
      <TextField fx:id="ipTextField" alignment="TOP_LEFT" focusTraversable="false" layoutX="411.0" layoutY="366.0" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="331.0" promptText="IP Address">
         <font>
            <Font size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </TextField>
      <CheckBox fx:id="rememberButton" layoutX="411.0" layoutY="452.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Remember me?" textFill="#b2b2b2">
         <font>
            <Font size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </CheckBox>
      <Button fx:id="connectButton" layoutX="670.0" layoutY="447.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#connectButtonAction" text="Connect" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Text fx:id="emptyForm" fill="#d00808" layoutX="483.0" layoutY="482.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Please fill in the empty forms" visible="false" wrappingWidth="184.22167682647705">
         <font>
            <Font size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </Text>
      <Text fx:id="invalidIP" fill="#d00808" layoutX="484.0" layoutY="483.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Invalid IP address. Try again" visible="false" wrappingWidth="172.00000762939453">
         <font>
            <Font size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </Text>
      <Text fx:id="authDown" fill="#d00808" layoutX="399.0" layoutY="484.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Authentication servers are currently down. Try again later" visible="false" wrappingWidth="353.00000762939453">
         <font>
            <Font size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </Text>
      <Text fx:id="serverDown" fill="#d00808" layoutX="411.0" layoutY="483.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Server is currently down. Contact admin and try again" visible="false" wrappingWidth="331.00000762939453">
         <font>
            <Font size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </Text>
      <Text fill="#b2b2b2" layoutX="50.0" layoutY="50.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Github • Twitter • Discord">
         <font>
            <Font size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </Text>
      <Text fill="#b2b2b2" layoutX="481.0" layoutY="117.0" stroke="#2196f3" strokeWidth="0.0" text="WELCOME BACK" textAlignment="CENTER">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="24.0" />
         </font>
      </Text>
      <TextFlow layoutX="920.0" layoutY="35.0" prefHeight="47.0" prefWidth="199.0">
         <children>
            <Text fill="#b2b2b2" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Not a member?">
               <font>
                  <Font size="14.0" />
               </font>
            </Text>
            <Hyperlink fx:id="hype" text="Register here">
               <font>
                  <Font size="14.0" />
               </font>
            </Hyperlink>
         </children>
      </TextFlow>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**STACK TRACE**

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.findResource(URLClassPath.java:1020)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$1.next(URLClassPath.java:267)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$1.hasMoreElements(URLClassPath.java:277)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$3$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:601)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$3$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:599)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$3.next(URLClassLoader.java:598)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$3.hasMoreElements(URLClassLoader.java:623)
    at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.next(CompoundEnumeration.java:45)
    at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.hasMoreElements(CompoundEnumeration.java:54)
    at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.next(CompoundEnumeration.java:45)
    at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.hasMoreElements(CompoundEnumeration.java:54)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:354)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:393)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:474)
    at javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder$1.run(FactoryFinder.java:352)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(FactoryFinder.java:341)
    at javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:313)
    at javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:227)
    at javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.newInstance(XMLInputFactory.java:154)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2472)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at Login.<init>(Login.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor2.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:927)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at Login.<init>(Login.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor2.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:927)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at Login.<init>(Login.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor2.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:927)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at Login.<init>(Login.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor2.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:927)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at Login.<init>(Login.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor2.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:927)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at Login.<init>(Login.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor2.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
```

Comment: You are trying to load a resource that tries to load the same controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused loading a fxml file from the `Login` class's constructor that causes another `Login` instance to be created using the same constructor. (The `Login` class is specified as value for the `fx:controller` attribute.)

You should either specify the controller when loading the fxml

```
public Login() throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Login.fxml"));
    loader.setController(this);
    loader.load();
}
```

```xml
<AnchorPane fx:id="root" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="648.0" prefWidth="1152.0" style="-fx-background-color: #2D3447;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
```

or by getting the controller instance from a fxml loader after loading:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Login.fxml"));
    loader.load();
    Login login = loader.getController();

    Scene loginScene = new Scene(login.getContent(), 1152, 648);
```

```xml
<AnchorPane fx:id="root" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="648.0" prefWidth="1152.0" style="-fx-background-color: #2D3447;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Login">
```

```
public Login() {
}
```

Comment: @jaxonlaing If the answer works, you should [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).